# Complex eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question: Suppose  is a 3×3 matrix with real entries that has a complex eigenvalue −1+8 with corresponding eigenvector

\begin{bmatrix}
1-2i\\ 
-1\\ 
8i
\end{bmatrix}

Find another eigenvalue and eigenvector for .

What should i do?

Comment: You should conjugate both sides of $$A\begin{bmatrix} 1-2i \\ -1 \\ 8i \end{bmatrix} = (-1+8i)\begin{bmatrix} 1-2i \\ -1 \\ 8i \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ has real entries so $\bar{A}=A$. Now just conjugate $Av=\lambda v$ you get that $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue corresponding to $\bar{v}$. (Remember this is only true because $A$ has real entries).

So $-1-8i$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $(1+2i,-1,-8i)^T$

Answer (score -1):

Real entries means the characteristic polynomial is real, so another eigenvalue is...? Then think about $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\
* & * & * \\
* & * & * \\
\end{bmatrix}v=(-1+8i)v$$ might be tweaked when $(-1+8i)$ is replaced by the other eigenvalue. Brute force it if you must then look for the pattern.